# In Apache Felix osgi container I never see my custom command

Tags: java, osgi, iot, apache-felix

I'm new to OSGI and I started with the enRoute Base Turorial.
I exported the provider project into a jar and wanted to deploy it into concierge/felix in both I was able to manage the lifecycle of the bundle (install/start/stop..) the issue is that the commands that I created I never can see them in there, but in eclipse the gogo commands are present and I can see/execute them.

I don't know how to figure this out, it says gogo commandNotFoundException.
Is these 2 options have any imact ? (runfw+runee).

I developed on windows and they are set on : 
runfw : org.eclipse.osgi and runee : JavaSE-1.8
and once I deploy this in linux, Felix/concierge container on a compact 1 Embedded Java SE it does the issue.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Start with checking that your bundle provides a service with the `osgi.command.scope` and `osgi.command.function` properties attached.

Comment: Hey thanks Neil for your answer.
Actually my bundle does provide such service.
Under Apache Felix I can see my commands once I run the help command, but in Concierge, even after installing the gogo bundles, I still no seeing my commands.

Comment: Can you show the output of the command `inspect cap service N` where N is the bundle ID of your bundle that provides the command service.

Comment: Hey Neil, thanks a lot for your help :)
Actually I found out what was the issue. As I'm running my bundles inside concierge and I've installed the gogo bundles. the issue is that there was 2 shells running : the gogo one and the concierge one. Once I stopped the concierge shell I was able to see my commands when I run the help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found out what was the issue.
As I'm running my bundles inside concierge and I've installed the gogo bundles.
the issue is that there was 2 shells running : the gogo one and the concierge one.
Once I stopped the concierge shell I was able to see my commands when I run the help.

Thanks.